# Implement power function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to understand how this program (copied from the eloquent javascript) works.

The actual program: a function with two parameter names (`base`, `exponent`), if you give those two parameters, the program should make the square of the base.

I tried to solve it on my own, but I failed.

Let me copy the code here:

```js
const power = function(base, exponent) {
  let result = 1;
  for (let count = 0; count < exponent; count++) {
    result *= base;
  }
  return result;
};
console.log(power(2, 10));
```

I understand well that I have to multiply the base with itself `exponent` times but I can not see how this program solves that. I had various other ideas, but... :)

I do not understand the `result` and `count` section, however it has been declared, but I can not see how it works.

Could somebody explain it to me? How does `count` affect the result?

Comment: Do you know how a [`for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) works?

Comment: why not to use `Math.pow` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow

Comment: @num8er Because the OP’s trying to learn programming, obviously.

Comment: Your question should be changed to "how for loop works"

Comment: @Xufox You know it's against of SO rules?

Comment: @num8er Asking for some explanation of code is not inherently against the SO rules, regardless of whether you’re a beginner or not.

Comment: @Xufox it's called "why my code does not work?"

Comment: @num8er That’s not what the OP is asking. Asking for debugging help would also be on-topic if it meets the MCVE criteria.

Comment: @Xufox SO "Could somebody explain it to me? How does count affect the result?" is not learning platform to explain how for...loop works. If every noob will ask such questions so people will not become professional and will just go copy-paste solutions to their problems.

Comment: @num8er So feel free to downvote the question and move on.

Comment: @num8er, I am wondering what makes some peeps to think that my question was against the rules/irrelevant. Let alone your you opinion "If every noob will ask such questions so people will not become professional and will just go copy-paste solutions to their problems." Please.

Comment: @num8er You know, if someone wants to know how things really work, that makes the questioner and maybe other people thinkn not the way around. Because doing something without knowing how it works makes people "go copy-paste. So I do not understand your logic and the same time I envy you for having so much time for commenting without real contribution.

Comment: @JánosFehér it's very optional moment. Unfortunately newcomers super lazy about to look for solution themselves or use their brains and time. In my time there was not google and yandex was not giving relevant results. I used to read official docs and use my imagination and math skills. But now... OK. I'm not against Your question. P.S. Since StackExchange has other special pages for code-reviews and etc cases: https://cs.stackexchange.com/  or https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @num8er I can understand well what you are saying. If I was a teacher I would say to the candidates in this case: watch the code and find out. It is doable, no doubt. I have spent many hours to understand this simple code, I mean really understand it. I posted a question and I have learned something about myself. I would like to write programs but only if I can manage it like children manage to build almost anything from legos. I will not copy anything, it is useless. Programming is maybe not for me, I am going to do everything to find it out. Thank you for the links. Regards.

Comment: @JánosFehér please don't understand my talk as offensive. Anyone can learn programming and do great projects. Just keep motivation and get it done to be proud of Yourself. That makes You to gain experience better.  And also bonus: watch this series https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCO1cgjhGzsSYb1rsB4bFe4Q/videos  he explains things very simple to understand. And I use his way of explaining when I've to mentor teammates.

Answer (score 3):

This is the implementation of the power, `x^y` (on calculator), function. You basically start by defining the product to be 1, because 1 is the invariant element for multiplication. And you go on and multiply the product by the `base` a `exponent` number of times times.

In your case, you have `x = 2, y = 10`:

```
result = 1 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 = 1024.
```

you have the first 1, and you multiply by 2 (base) 10 (exponent) times.

Comment: Still working on the same code, thank you for your answer. I try to explain the for-line, because that is the only thing unclear to me. I wonder if I am correct. The "count"=0 because it is the lowest value the exponent can take. Count must be lower than exponent (the base is the first value) and the same time must take its maximum value, hence the increment operator.  What I really do not understand: how does "count" do anything if it is only inside the for() and nowhere after that?

Comment: @JánosFehér The use of `count` is to multiply the exact number of times. This number of times is `exponent`. Notice the example I listed: if you have `exponent = 10` than you multiply by 2 (which is the base) 10 times. You can do it manually by wrting 10 times  `( * 2)` as I did. Or you can use a for loop, which goes from `count = 0 to count= 9 (so 10 times)`, so whatever is in the loop is repetead 10 times. What is in the loop ? Multiplication by the base (in our case base = 2).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Weird, after reading your opinion I have just realized that I did not understand the meaning of "count=9" earlier. I should have had. :)

Comment: Np, the important thing is that you understood ;)